# App engine import issue (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, google-app-engine-python

I have a App engine project like this:

```
- project
    - xlutils
        * __init__.py (blank)
        * copy.py
        * filter.py
    - other libs
    - main.py (calls made from here)
```

In the code I try to import xlutils directly ('import xlutils'), but doesn't work the calls in the code like 'xlutils.copy.copy(w)' and also doesn't import submodules like this:

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlutils.filter import process,XLRDReader,XLWTWriter
```

When I try to do some of that imports I see only a blank page, without visible errors.

Someone knows the correct way to import it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to know if it is a correct way to import the 'xlutils' library

Comment: and from where are you making the import calls?

Comment: from the root of the project (sorry for forget that)

Comment: Have a read of the docs on how to include third party libraries.  It's in the section discussing the sandbox.

Comment: Also always remember to check the console for errors, rather than the web response

Answer (score 0):

In main.py

```
from xlutils import copy
from xlutils.filter
```

You will then call the classes/methods like below

```
filter.process
filter.XLRDReader
filter.XLWTWriter
```